# Ruby On Rails - Controller and view blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am stuck and unable to proceed on my Ruby on Rails tutorial.

I am doing a Ruby on Rails tutorial using a mac.

I have created a new Ruby on Rails project in `Users/username/sites/simple_cms`

I am using `Webrick` server

I started the server using `rails s` command and as expected, when navigating to the `localhost:3000` the public `index` page was displayed.

I then added a controller and view using the following command in the route directory:

```sh
rails generate controller demo index
```

The controller and view were successfully created:

My `routes` file:

```rb
SimpleCms::Application.routes.draw do
  get "demo/index"
```

My `demo_controller` File:

```rb
class DemoController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

My View file is now located in `views/demo/index.html.erb`:

```html
<h1>Demo#index</h1>

<p>hello world</p>
```

I then started Webrick again and entered:

```
http://localhost:3000/demo/index
```

but a blank page is displayed.

Comment: Can you please format your code? on a mac you select the code in the editor and press CMD + K.

Comment: No worries. My first post. From now on I know. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Try starting up your rails server, enter `http://localhost:3000/demo/index` in a browser and then go back to the terminal window where you started rails. It should show a long log feed. Copy that into the question and that should give us some better clues as to what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

add `root to 'demo#index'`  to routes file http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your route as follows

```
get "index" => "demo#index"
```

then you can access the site with `localhost:3000/index`

But if this is your root path you can also do

```
root "demo#index"
```

to access the site with `localhost:3000`

In this case demo refers to your controller and index to your action in the controller.

Comment: This is just wrong. `get "demo/index"` creates the following route `demo_index GET  /demo/index(.:format) demo#index` it may be idiosyncratic but it's not the cause of whatever the issue is here. A routing error would most likely result in an error page being show. Not an empty response.